# Nginx and Node.js — am I doing it wrong?

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

> “If #nginx isn’t sitting in front of your node server, you’re probably doing it wrong.”
>
> — Bryan Hughes via Twitter

For a short while now, I have been making applications with Node.js and, as Mr.Hughes advises, serving them with Nginx as a reverse proxy. But I am not sure that I am doing it correctly **because I can still access my Node.js application over the internet without going through the Nginx server**.

---

At its core, the typical application is quite simple. It is served with ExpressJS like this:

```js
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

// ...

app.listen(3000);
```

and Nginx is configured as a reverse-proxy like so:

```
# ...

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# ...
```

And this works wonderfully! However I have noticed a behaviour that I am not sure is desirable, and may defeat a large portion of the purpose of using Nginx as a reverse-proxy in the first place:

Assuming example.org is a domain name pointing to my server, I can navigate to `http://www.example.org:3000` and interact with my application from anywhere, without touching the Nginx server.

The typical end user would never have any reason to navigate to `http://<whatever-the-server-host-name-or-IP-may-be>:<the-port-the-application-is-being-served-on>`, so this would never effect them. My concern, though, is that this may have security implications that a not-so-end-user could take advantage of.

---

1. Should the application be accessible directly even though Nginx is being used as a reverse-proxy?
2. How can you configure the application so that it is only be available to the local machine / network / Nginx server?

Comment: It seems that your server is setup in such a way it allows connections to any port, which should not be possible. I mean i have ubuntu 14.04 on my server with nginx and a few apps on ports 4001 to 4005 and i can't access them with myserver.com:4001 etc. and i haven't done anything to prevent that. I'm not an expert but i think you should use some firewall to prevent connections to any port that you don't want to be exposed. I've read somewhere that by default(on ubuntu) only ports up to 1023 are accessible from outside. Ports 1024 to 65535 shouldn't be accessible.

Answer (score 4):

1. It is best not to be available directly (imho).
2. You can specify accepted [`hostname`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen):

   `app.listen(3000, 'localhost');`